# How to define a child element on a Jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using waypoints.js and animate.css as this example: http://miguelmanchego.com/samples/2014/jquery-mostrar-animaciones.htm to add animations when scrolling.

If I have the structure:

```
<div class="FlyWithMe">
   <div>I am a bird!</div>
   <div>Mee too!</div>
</div>
```

I can of course animate them with:

```
    $('.FlyWithMe').waypoint(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass( 'bounceIn animated' );
    }
```

But how can I define the child element to animate them instead of a container?

```
    $('.FlyWithMe').waypoint(function() {
        $(this>child).toggleClass( 'bounceIn animated' );
    }
```

Of course I could add the class to the child element directly but this is just an example of a more complex case.

Comment: Oh, let me take a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use find function to select children:

```
$(this).find('div').toggleClass( 'bounceIn animated' );
```